# Prove that all dihedral groups of degree $4$ are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, dihedral-groups

I was studying about group theory when I came across a very well-known statement that:

> Any two dihedral groups of degree $4$ are isomorphic.

I have two questions from here:

- What’s actually is a degree of a group? I have heard about the order of a group, but never heard anything about degree of a group.
- Secondly, how are they concluding the fact that any two dihedral groups of degree $4$ are isomorphic?

I know that a group is called a “dihedral group of degree $4$” if it has only two generators $a, b$ such that $o(a) = 4$, $o(b) = 2$ and $ba = a^3b$. From these facts I proved that a  dihedral group of degree $4$ always has eight elements.

My proof for my above assertion goes as follows:

> If $a, b$ are two generators of the above group then we have $G = \langle a, b \rangle$. Hence we can say
> $$
>   G = \{ a^{i_1} b^{j_1} a^{i_2} b^{j_2} \dotsm a^{i_n} b^{j_n} \mid i_t, j_t \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq t \leq n, n \in \mathbb{N} \}
> $$
> Now, we have, $b a = a^3 b$ due to which every element  of $G$ is of the form $a^i b^j$, where $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $a^4 = e$ and $b^2 = e$, so $G = \{ a^i b^j \mid 0 \leq i \leq 4, 0 \leq j \leq 2\}$. Now, $|G| \leq 8$.
>
> Since, $o(a) = 4$, so $P = \{ e, a, a^2, a^3 \}$ are distinct. Also, since $a \neq b \neq e$, hence $Q = \{ b, a b, a^2 b, a^3 b\}$, are distinct as well. Now we claim $P \cap Q = \emptyset$. This is because $b \neq e$, $b \neq a$, if $b = a^2$, then $a^3 b = b a b = b a$, due to which $b = e$, a contradiction. Also, if $b = a^3$, then $a^3 b = b^2 = b a$, then $a = b$, a contradiction again. Now, if $ab = e$, then $a^3b = a^2 = ba$, a contradiction. Also, $a b \neq a$, $a b \neq a^2$. If $a b = a^3$, then $a^2 = b$, a contradiction shown in a previous case. Also, from previous cases we can say $a^2b \neq e, a, a^2, a^3$. Similarly, $a^3b \neq e, a, a^2, a^3$. Hence $G = P \cup Q = \{e, a, a^2, a^3, b, a b, a^2 b, a^3b \}$. Hence, $|G| \leq 8$ and $|G| = 8$.

This completes the proof.  But I don’t know how to show that:

> Any two dihedral groups of degree $4$ are isomorphic.

I think that if we consider two dihedral groups of degree $4$ say  , $D_4$ and $D'_4$ such that $D_4=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, b, a b, a^2 b, a^3b \}$ and $D'_4=\{\overline e, p, p^2, p^3, r, p r, p^2 r, p^3r \}$, and consider the following bijective mapping $f:D_4\longrightarrow D_4'$ such that $f(e)=\overline e,f(a)=p,f(a^2)=p^2,\cdots ,f(a^3b)=p^3r$, then we just need to show that $f$ is a homomorphism . Now, I dknt get how to show this as well . One way is there if we form each pairs of $(a^ib^j,a^cb^d)$ and compute , but that becomes an unusually long process as we have to do $64$ computations manually ...

Comment: To make the confusion complete, some authors denote the dihedral group with $8$ elements with $D_8$ , others with $D_4$. And I neither ever heard of the "degree of a group".

Comment: Neither have I.  I figured the caveat might be $D_n$. (Or uh, $D_{2n}$).

Comment: Sometimes there's caveats in mathematics.   I was once thrown by "the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$", which,  of course only makes sense for integers coprime to $n$.

Comment: The symmetric group $S_n$ is usually said to have "degree $n$" (not to be confused with its order, which is $n!$). I think that, likewise, it is fair enough to name "degree" of the dihedral group $D_n$ the number of sides of the regular polygon whose $D_n$ is the group of simmetries (namely, "degree" = $n$, "order" = $2n$). Though I agree that, besides these two special cases, the concept of "degree" is not valid for all the (finite) groups.

Comment: Of course,  one might also say that the author should be more careful.   For instance in my example talk about a reduced system of residues.

Comment: @Devo Thanks!but what about the isomorphism part? (Even if I ignore the degree notion in this context)....

Comment: @Devo, in the light of your comment and given the fact (aka Cayley's theorem) that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some $S_n$ I am tempted to say that the degree of a finite group might be the smallest such $n$.

Comment: @eggnog: your example isn't that weird. Given a ring $R$ one usually speaks of the multiplicative group of $R$ which obviously consists of the invertible elements (aka the units) in $R$. The integers mod $n$ are a ring.

Comment: Right.   It's the group of units.  @AndreaMori it is obvious but at first I was thrown a little.

Comment: Please work on your punctuation.

Comment: You are right, @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. I took it for granted probably being biased by the particular case $\mu(D_4)=4$. But in general $\mu(D_n)\le n$. I'm going to delete my comment above.

Comment: There are caveats in mathematics: the definitions.   Alot of times only certain people know them.  Take *number fields*.  They're algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$.  But of course not everybody knows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to notice that the information you have completely determines the multiplication table for the group.

Indeed, you know that the group is generated by $a$ and $b$ and has $o(a)=4$, $o(b)=2$ and $ba=a^3b$.

As you observed, from the last equality alone we can conclude that $G=\{a^ib^j:i,j\in\mathbb Z\}$, and using the fact that $a$ and $b$ have orders $4$ and $2$, respectively, we can improve this description to $$G=\{a^ib^j:0\leq i<4,0\leq j<2\}.$$
Moreover, then $8$ elements listed here are pairwise different. Indeed, let us suppose that $i$, $i'$, $j$ and $j'$ are integers such that $0\leq i,i'<4$, $0\leq j,j'<2$ and $a^ib^j=a^{i'}b^{j'}$. If $j\neq j'$, then we can suppose without loss of generality that $j=0$ and $j'=1$, so the equality $a^ib^j=a^{i'}b^{j'}$ tells us that $a^{i-i'}=b$: now $a^3b=ba=a^{i-i'}a=aa^{i-i'}=ab$, so $a=a^3$, and this is absurd, since $a$ has order $4$. It follows that $j=j'$ and, since $a^ib^j=a^{i'}b^{j'}$, that $a^i=a^{i'}$: as the order of $a$ is $4$, this implies that $i-i'$ is divisible by $4$, and since both $i$ and $i'$ are in $\{0,1,2,3\}$, that they are actually equal.

The conclusion of all this is that $G$ has exactly $8$ elements, which are $$a^ib^j,\qquad\text{with $0\leq i<4$ and $0\leq j<2$.}$$
Now using the equality $ba=a^3b$ we can easily check that $ba^i=a^{3i}b$ for all $i\in\mathbb Z$, and using that, in turn, that $$a^ib^j\cdot a^{i'}b^{j'}=a^{i+3i'}b^{j+j'}$$ for all choices of $i$, $i'$, $j$ and $j'$ in $\mathbb Z$. This tells us how to write down the complete multiplication table of $G$.

Comment: But I dont get how the fact that  "any two dihedral groups of degree $4$ are isomorphic " .  Is this the way we must proceed (?): we consider the mapping $f$ such that :$f(a^ib^j)=p^ir^j\forall a^ib^j\in D_4$ . Also, we find that, (as you noted) $a^ib^ja^{i'}b^{j'}=a^i(b^ja^{i'})b^{j'}=a^i(a^{3i'}b^{j})b^{j'}=a^{i+3i'}b^{j+j'}$ (from the relation $ba=a^3b\implies b^{j}a^{i'}=a^{3i'}b^{j}$). Hence, $f(a^{i}b^{j}a^{i'}b^{j'})=f(a^{i+3i'}b^{j+j'})=p^{i+3i'}r^{j+j'}=p^ip^{3i'}r^{j}r^{j'}=p^ir^jp^{i'}r^{j'}=f(a^ib^j)f(a^{i'}b^{j'})$, due to which $f$ is a homomorphism

Comment: Also, $f$ is onto as $\forall p^ir^j\in D_4'\exists a^ib^j\in D_4$ such that $f(a^ib^j)=p^ir^j$, and $f$ is injective as well , as if $a^ib^j\neq a^hb^k$, then, if , $f(a^ib^j)=f(a^hb^k)=p^ir^j=p^hb^k$ and as you noted, $h=i, k=j$ , a contradiction. Hence, $f$ is an isomorphism from $D_4$ onto $D'_4$. Is this correct ?...

Comment: Thank you! However, can you please explain how is this $b^ja^i=a^{3i}b^j$? As I used this fact, in my proof and today, it striked me, where did I come accross this? I mean how does $ba=a^{3}b\implies b^ja^i=a^{3i}b^j$?... But you ascertained it was correct...So how is this statement valid?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [von Dyck's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonDycksTheorem.html) to get a bijective homomorphism (that's an isomorphism) onto $D_4=\langle a,b\mid a^4,b^2,(ab)^2\rangle,$ for each such $G$.

Note that it's an easy consequence of the relators that the order of the presentation group is at most $8$.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am learning elementary group theory and I dont understand the theorem you mention so if you have any elementary ways to prove this , it would really be very much helpful....

Comment: The upshot is that a given presentation defines a unique group.   Maybe take a look here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4576216/1070376

Comment: Point taken.   But it is easy to show that the given presentation has order at most $8$.  Suppose I should add this to my answer.   @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez